# How to exclude folder from Recursive Get-Childpath

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

Im trying to run a recursive search through all of C Drive, but wish to exclude Windows & Program Files.

Confused as to why this doesn't work.

```
$b = if(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -Force -filter *.exe -Exclude Users,Windows | ? {$_.Name -eq 'firefox.exe'})
{
    return $true
} 
else {
    return $false
}

$b
```

I know it isn't working as I get access denied errors due to the drive permissions.

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\ccmsetup' is denied.
At line:1 char:9
+ $b = if(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -Force -filter *.exe -Exclud ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\ccmsetup:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Settle on a single PowerShell version in the tags. You're not running all of them.

Answer (score 2):

The `-Exclude` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` is not very reliable and for this particular case, the process would be quite slow using this cmdlet. I would recommend you to use a [`Collections.Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?view=net-6.0) and [`IO.Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-6.0) to enumerate files and folders.

Below code will attempt to find **all appearances of `firefox.exe`**, however, if you wish to stop at **first appearance** you should uncomment `break outer`.

Note that this requires you to add the **absolute paths of the folders** you wish to exclude to the `$pathToExclude` array.

**`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($target)`** could be replaced by **`[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($target, '*firefox.exe')`**.

```
$pathToExclude = @(
    'C:\Users'
    'C:\Windows'
)

$queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new()
$queue.Enqueue('C:\')

:outer while($queue.Count) {
    $target = $queue.Dequeue()
    foreach($path in $pathToExclude) {
        if($target.StartsWith($path)) {
            continue outer
        }
    }

    try {
        foreach($dir in [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($target)) {
            $queue.Enqueue($dir)
        }

        foreach($file in [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($target)) {
            if($file -like '*firefox.exe') {
                # return the full path of the file if it contains `firefox.exe`
                $file

                # if you want to stop the loop at the first finding of the file,
                # uncomment below line:
                # break outer
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        # Ignoring folders we're unable to enumerate
        # You can however add these directories to a list or display error messages
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to wrap my head around [the `-Exclude` semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?#example-5-get-child-items-using-the-exclude-parameter) in combination with `-Filter`/`-Include` and `-Path` either with or without trailing `*`, but oh boy, this is broken beyond any hope of repair. Re-implementing this from scratch really seems to be the sane approach in comparison.

Comment: I think you could simplify a little bit by doing `continue outer` directly, instead of using the `$exclude` flag.

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to upvote https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15159 /cc @Tomalak

Comment: @Tomalak Excellent call with the labeled `continue`, thank you! I'm not a fan of `Get-ChildItem` in general, it's extremely slow.